# If structKeyExists and value is this otherwise do this

Tags: coldfusion

What I am trying to do is see if `session.checkout.info.gender_1` exists then if it does also check whether it is Male or Female. Depending on which one it is have the value for cfpdfformparam either M or F so that it fits better on the form. I have tried "IsDefined", is not "". Will someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

```
    <cfif structKeyExists(session, 'checkout.info.gender_1') and trim("session.checkout.info.gender_1") neq "Female">
        <cfpdfformparam name="sex" value="M">
</cfif> <!---Section1 Owner Sex--->
    <cfif structKeyExists(session, 'checkout.info.gender_1') and trim("session.checkout.info.gender_1") neq "Male">
        <cfpdfformparam name="sex" value="F">
</cfif>
```

Comment: Why are you using `neq` (`not equals`). Don't you want `eq`?

Comment: hahaha I was just trying everything I could think of I tried eq also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should layer your tests. Your test should be more like this...

```
<cfif isDefined("session")
    and structKeyExists(session, 'checkout') 
    and structKeyExists(session.checkout, 'info') 
    and structKeyExists(session.checkout.info, 'gender_1') >

    <cfif session.checkout.info.gender_1 eq "Female">
         do this
    <cfelse>
         do that
    </cfif>

</cfif>
```

Answer (score 4):

In your code example the `trim` function is actually trimming the string "session.checkout.info.gender_1" not the variable.  Remove the quotes and try again.

```
<cfif structKeyExists(session, 'checkout.info.gender_1') and trim(session.checkout.info.gender_1) neq "Female">
    <cfpdfformparam name="sex" value="M">
</cfif> <!---Section1 Owner Sex--->
<cfif structKeyExists(session, 'checkout.info.gender_1') and trim(session.checkout.info.gender_1) neq "Male">
    <cfpdfformparam name="sex" value="F">
</cfif>
```

Comment: errrrr its still not working its not reflecting the M or F its just blank for that field :/

Comment: so it must not be reading those lines its just trying to say does #session.checkout.info.gender_1# exist and if its male put M for the value and if its Female put F for the value :( Why am I making this so complicated :(

Answer (score 1):

This is a formatted comment.  Troubleshoot your if/else logic like this:

```
<cfif myVariable is theExpectedValue>
yes
<cfelse>
no
<cfdump var = "expected #theExpectedValue# and got #myVariable#>
</cfif>
```

Once you have the logic sorted out, insert the actual code for each condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<cfif structKeyExists(session, 'checkout.info.gender_1') and len(trim(session.checkout.info.gender_1))>
    <cfpdfformparam name="sex" value="#UCase(Left(Trim(session.checkout.info.gender_1),1))#">
<cfelse>
    <cfpdfformparam name="sex" value="Undefined">
</cfif>
```

You may not ever actually want your pdf report to say undefined for gender, but this will at least allow you to do some debugging.

However, since you're checking for gender's existence, it seems it is optional and in that case, you could use the same code to set gender's value to `X` or `Not Set`, when the variable is not defined or empty.

And since you're matching Male to M and Female to F, we can use `Left()` to just get the first letter.

Comment: hmmm this exact line printed out undefined

Comment: So what you've got is either the variable is undefined, or the len is equalling 0. Try removing the and `and` everything after and see if it passes.